# c# How to populate list of string names into a resource file

Tags: c#

I have a list of ~200 strings names that I want to populate into a Resources.resx file.

Is there a simple / easy way to do this, or do I have to copy paste into the editor one at a time.  Or modify the underlying code for each option?

Comment: Why not just assemble them in something like Excel, name in one column and value in the second, and then copy/paste them en masse? Or just assemble them in a file tab separated (e.g. `name{TAB}value{NEWLINE}name{TAB}value`), and copy/paste en masse.

Comment: Take a look at ResXResourceWriter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resxresourcewriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done like this. Use your own file format and delimiter.

### strings.dat

```
string001,hello world
string002,this is another
```

### code.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Resources;

namespace CreateRF
{
    class CreateRF
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@".\strings.dat", Encoding.UTF8);
            using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@".\resources.resx"))
            {

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    string[] pair = line.Split(',');   
                    resx.AddResource(pair[0], pair[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```